# Save Selected Features in QGIS 3.4 Model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to build some models I have in QGIS 2.18. Each model uses the "Save Selected Features" geoalgorithm so that the model only runs on selected features in the source vector layer.

In 3.4 there is no "Save Selected Features". There is an "Extract Selected Features" but I am unable to get the "polygons to lines" algorithm to point to it as it does in 2.18.

This is the 2.18 model
[image]

Comment: Define the result of the selection as final, then it should be saved.

Comment: It doesn't allow the "Polygons to line" algorithm to point to a final output of the selection. Just the source. I've kind of got around it by using a Vector Features input which allows a selected features only option. I've been able to use the "Extract Selected Features" in my other models fine. For some reason Polygons to lines just won't point to it.